# Rabbitmq drop the connection with consumer silent while ioloop stays alive

Tags: python, rabbitmq, pika

I wrote a consumer script using pika.SelectConnection() which simulate this offical script:
https://github.com/pika/pika/blob/master/examples/asynchronous_consumer_example.py

I run this consumer on kubernetes.
It's running well at the first two or three days, After two or three days, the connection dropped silent, no exception, no error logging, but the consumer ioloop still alive . I can see the TCP connection still on in the consumer docker.But on the broke side, (I'm not sure if the connection closed) under the queue ,there is no consumer, no unack, and the message cann't be consume.

Environment:

pika 1.0.1

rabbitmq 3.7.13

kubernetes v1.12.2

kazoo 2.6.1 (I don't think this is related)

I set the heartbeat to 0, the queue and message are durable.Messages haven't been send frequently, the queue is idled for a long time，but my script have reconnect strategy.

At the beginning, I tried pika.BlockingConnection(), it has the same problem, then I tried pika.SelectConnection(),like I said above, it's the same.I checked the log on rabbitmq server, nothing helped.I have no idea how to locate the problem now.

The log in rabbitmq server:

2019-06-03 16:59:35.963 [info] <0.5980.31> accepting AMQP connection <0.5980.31> (192.168.133.127:47622 -> 192.168.133.3:5672)

2019-06-03 16:59:35.968 [info] <0.5980.31> connection <0.5980.31> (192.168.133.127:47622 -> 192.168.133.3:5672): user 'perfee' authenticated and granted access to vhost 'perfee'

2019-06-03 16:59:51.369 [warning] <0.5980.31> closing AMQP connection <0.5980.31> (192.168.133.127:47622 -> 192.168.133.3:5672, vhost: 'perfee', user: 'perfee'):
client unexpectedly closed TCP connection

2019-06-03 17:03:05.235 [info] <0.6216.31> accepting AMQP connection <0.6216.31> (192.168.133.160:37214 -> 192.168.133.3:5672)

2019-06-03 17:03:05.255 [info] <0.6216.31> connection <0.6216.31> (192.168.133.160:37214 -> 192.168.133.3:5672): user 'perfee' authenticated and granted access to vhost 'perfee'

2019-06-03 17:05:22.626 [info] <0.6216.31> closing AMQP connection <0.6216.31> (192.168.133.160:37214 -> 192.168.133.3:5672, vhost: 'perfee', user: 'perfee')

2019-06-03 17:06:04.613 [info] <0.6420.31> accepting AMQP connection <0.6420.31> (192.168.133.160:37220 -> 192.168.133.3:5672)

2019-06-03 17:06:04.635 [info] <0.6420.31> connection <0.6420.31> (192.168.133.160:37220 -> 192.168.133.3:5672): user 'perfee' authenticated and granted access to vhost 'perfee'

2019-06-03 17:06:06.444 [info] <0.6420.31> closing AMQP connection <0.6420.31> (192.168.133.160:37220 -> 192.168.133.3:5672, vhost: 'perfee', user: 'perfee')

2019-06-03 17:14:02.462 [info] <0.6934.31> accepting AMQP connection <0.6934.31> (192.168.133.160:37226 -> 192.168.133.3:5672)

2019-06-03 17:14:02.478 [info] <0.6934.31> connection <0.6934.31> (192.168.133.160:37226 -> 192.168.133.3:5672): user 'perfee' authenticated and granted access to vhost 'perfee'

2019-06-03 17:16:14.889 [info] <0.7103.31> accepting AMQP connection <0.7103.31> (172.16.20.190:63064 -> 192.168.133.3:5672)

2019-06-03 17:16:15.013 [warning]  lager_file_backend dropped 2 messages in the last second that exceeded the limit of 50 messages/sec

Comment: I set prefetch_count to 1

Comment: This is a problem we are still experiencing with `asyncio` and pika. We have a retry mechanism in place to restore the connection but it does make it difficult to handle messages when the connection can be dropped.

Comment: @Tim,Your retry mechanism ,does it work?

Comment: Kind of, it restores connectivity, but we could have lost messages in the meantime and also causes issues if we need to send events. I'd rather fix the cause though.

Comment: @Tim,Did you find the cause?

Comment: No is still an ongoing issue.

Comment: **Do not set the heartbeat to 0!** What is in the RabbitMQ logs?

Comment: @LukeBakken Thanks,I'm going to add heartbeat now. I added some logs above.  There are a lot of "client unexpectedly closed TCP connection" in the log. But I have created multiple queues on a same broke, and I ran the consumer on k8s, the connection's port number have been changed,so I cann't locate the queue I'm checking exactly. And the broke dropped the consumer after two or three days its started, I don't know exactly when it happened.I don't think the log I added above is the log from the queue I'm checking.

Comment: It's solved. The cause is I turned off the heartbeat.After I turn on the heartbeat, the app have ran on production environment for many days, the connections is still on.