# Why do Consumers disconnect from the queue silently during long idles using Pika RabbitMQ?

Tags: rabbitmq, pika, messagebroker

In my company we are currently facing a strange behavour using rabbitMQ. One of our microservices hosted in a Kubernetes Cluster is built in **Python** (the others in **Java** and they don't show this problem) and communicates using **Pika** implementation for RabbitMQ.

During the week the microservice works just fine, in the weekend it is not used and still up and running. On monday trying to publish a message on this microservice queue results in them remaining unacked because all the consumers have disconnected.
Looking in the code logs, there is absolutely nothing: no error, no exception thrown, nothing at all. **The service remains idle without noticing it is disconnected from the queue**.

In the first implementation we had a **BlockingConnection**, but referencing this issue https://github.com/pika/pika/issues/877 and suspecting some kind of idle termination, we moved to **SelectConnection** using **ioloops**.
The **heartbeat** is configured with standard 60s with broker negotation.
I assume it is not a problem in the rabbitMQ broker because every other microservice in Java is working just fine and the connection keeps alive for weeks.

A close similiar issue I found is [Rabbitmq drop the connection with consumer silent while ioloop stays alive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56422031/rabbitmq-drop-the-connection-with-consumer-silent-while-ioloop-stays-alive), the issuer solved it by restoring the heartbeat that he disabled, but for our use-case it is already enabled.

Here a link to github with a close implementation of the Consumer we are using: https://github.com/stefanofal-altilia/idle-disconnecting-rabbitmq/blob/main/consumer.py .

The same code can be found below.
Using pika 1.2.0

```
import pika
from pika import ConnectionParameters


def handle(ch, method, properties, body):
    try:
        print("Method called handle")
        print("Message with id {} arrived".format(properties.correlation_id))
        body = "I recevied a message!"
        ch.basic_publish(exchange='',
                         routing_key=properties.reply_to,
                         properties=pika.BasicProperties(correlation_id=properties.correlation_id),
                         body=str.encode(body))
        print("Response sended")
        ch.basic_ack(delivery_tag=method.delivery_tag)
        print("Method ended handle")
    except BaseException as e:
        print(
            "Fatal error on message broker class {} method {} error {}".format("RabbitMQConsumer", "handle",
                                                                               str(e)))


def consume_select_connection():
    print("Method called consume_select_connection")

    def on_open(conn):
        print("Method called on_open")
        conn.channel(on_open_callback=on_channel_open)
        print("Method ended on_open")

    def on_channel_open(channel):
        print("Method called on_channel_open")
        channel.queue_declare("annotation-request-queue", passive=False, durable=True,
                              exclusive=False, auto_delete=False)
        channel.basic_consume("annotation-request-queue", on_message_callback=handle)
        print("Method ended on_channel_open")

    credentials = pika.PlainCredentials(username="guest",
                                        password="guest")
    parameters = ConnectionParameters(
        host="localhost",
        port=5672,
        credentials=credentials,
        blocked_connection_timeout=60)
    connection = pika.SelectConnection(parameters=parameters, on_open_callback=on_open)
    try:
        print("I/O start")
        #  Block on the IOLoop
        connection.ioloop.start()

    # Catch a Keyboard Interrupt to make sure that the connection is closed cleanly
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("keyboard exception")
        # Gracefully close the connection
        connection.close()
    except BaseException as e:
        print(("BASE exception: ", str(e)))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    consume_select_connection()
```

Comment: Hi Stefano, I'm a member of the RabbitMQ core eng team and the primary maintainer of Pika. At a glance I don't see anything obviously wrong with the code. Stack Overflow isn't the best forum for diagnosing issues, so if you don't mind starting a discussion [here](https://github.com/pika/pika/discussions) I'm happy to assist. Please be sure to include RabbitMQ version, Erlang version, and any RabbitMQ log messages that pertain to this issue. Thanks!